# Is it possible to buy and create an invoice on eBay as a business?

Tags: ebay, user-accounts

I created a business account on eBay but it seems to be only for selling things.

I would like to buy an item for my business computer and would like to have an invoice for it, having my company name on it.

In my first try it seemed to be possible to include the company name on the billing address as Street Address but I'm not sure if this will result in a proper, legal invoice for my company.

Is this possible to have a legal VAT invoice for my company?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VAT is usually for the UK and EU, not the US, so not sure if you are asking about the same thing.

If you want your business name to appear on any item you buy, simply add it to the shipping address when you go to checkout in PayPal.

Just be aware that having a 'business' account with eBay, does not mean you are legitimised as a business in whatever country you reside, you need to apply for that from your government.​​